# Current Place error The operation couldn’t be completed. (Google Place SDK, autocomplete error)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

Since 2 days, I have the following error message :
 "An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support)."

This is my code :

```
 -(void)GetCurrentLocation {

    [_locationPoint setHidden:NO];
    [_placesClient currentPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlaceLikelihoodList *likelihoodList, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Current Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        for (GMSPlaceLikelihood *likelihood in likelihoodList.likelihoods) {
            GMSPlace *place = likelihood.place;
            NSLog(@"Current Place name %@ at likelihood %g", place.name, likelihood.likelihood);
            NSLog(@"Current Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
            _depart.text = place.formattedAddress;
            NSLog(@"Current Place attributions %@", place.attributions);
            NSLog(@"Current PlaceID %@", place.placeID);
            NSLog(@"coordinates %f,%f",place.coordinate.latitude,place.coordinate.longitude);
        }

    }];
}
```

I don't understand, I have not changed my code and this error appeared suddenly.

Google Maps SDK for iOS and Google Places API for iOS version: 2.0.26137.0

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you have crossed **1000** click per day limit you can extend your limits through purchase Google Web service APIs so [read google official doc.](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is happening when you update your `podFile`to new versions and change `podFile.Lock`
Go to old `podFile.Lock` and see google map versions. 
If there is any change, just copy old `podiflie.Lock` and paste in a current.

Pod install and I think it will work like a charm.